# How to update database model on a deployed asp mvc web site without losing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to update database schema (model) in asp mvc website after it is deployed, without losing any previous data?

I have just deployed an MVC5 website to azure web site. Everything is fine, thus I started to uploading some data. Then I figured out something that I needed to update. It is simple, I just want to make a slight change in its database schema.

In local machine (development stage), we can just run

```
Update-Database
```

on package manager console. And here is the question? how to do the same idea to the published version? I have not tried to re publish my solution, fearing that the data will be lost (the data is plenty, too much to re upload).

I am using entity framework 6 code first with migration enabled:

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
```

All I want to do is just adding an attribute to one of the data row:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name {get;set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

to:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name {get;set; }

    [AllowHtml] //ADDING THIS ONLY
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can, among other solution, use this

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, Configuration>());
```

where `BlogContext` is your context and `Configuration` is the configuration class (the one descending from `DbMigrationsConfiguration<T>`) generated by code first.

Of course you have to republish your application (at least binary part).

Please also read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx, specially the last paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Nevertheless, I just want to confirm one more time: If I use this setting, the database schema on the deployed website will be updated, but there will not be any data lost? Am I correct? So it will not drop the database, it will not run the seed method. It will solely update the schema with the existing database? Sorry for being too paranoia :S

Comment: never too paranoiac. I recommend to backup the database and restore it on a test/preprod environment and test the migration before deploy to prod.

Comment: Helo sir, I would like to know more about MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, I just followed as you wrote, but then there occured a foreign key conflict. Here is my question: let's say I have a dummy data in my offline development, then I deployed it to azure. After it was online, I removed the dummy data and start uploading real data. Then I wanted to make a change in the schema (just changing from int to double), so as you said, I used the migratetolatestversion. What whould happen to the data? will the dummy data that I had offline be transfered and cause the conflict?

Comment: @ Ace I have `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false` and if I add this line of code `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, Configuration>());` to my `Global.asax.cs` will there be any risk?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the scariness that is Code First Migrations in a production environment! One thing to note, if you enable automatic migrations, you can never revert the migration. Instead, it's recommended that you don't do automatic migrations. Instead, from your console, run `add-migration "migrationName"`. This will add a migration to your migrations folder with an up and a down method, where you can see all the changes that are related to that migration. You can see what sql will be run against the database by running update-database -script. The changes will not actually be run, but you can see what sql is generated. [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) is a good walkthrough on Code First Migrations and deployment and all the changes that are necessary in the web.config file.

I believe that allowing data loss is turned off by default when you use automatic migrations.