# The model backing the 'myContext' context has changed since the database was created (Error on Production)

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a MVC 5 application.

My Automatic Migrations is disabled:

```
 public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }
```

I modified one of my model and I used EF Migration tool `enable/add-migration` and ran the `update-database` in EF and my database was updated on my dev machine. I tested an everything works great.

I then used Visual Studio to Publish the project to deploy this release to my production server but how come I still got this same error?

"**The model backing the 'myContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).**"

Please tell me what is it that I have to do more to get this working on my production?

Thanks

Update:

I followed the advise from this thread

[Link to thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780368/how-to-update-database-model-on-a-deployed-asp-mvc-web-site-without-losing-data)

> you can, among other solution, use this
>
> Database.SetInitializer(new
>   `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, Configuration>());` where
>   BlogContext is your context and Configuration is the configuration
>   class (the one descending from DbMigrationsConfiguration) generated
>   by code first.
>
> Of course you have to republish your application (at least binary
>   part).

I basically added that line of code to my `Application_Start` in the `Global.asax.cs` and it seems working for me. My database on my production is updated. But, I am not sure if this is a safe way of doing it. Is there any risk in doing this? I do not want to lose any data on production.

Comment: Do you use identity 2 in your project?

Comment: @ Soheil  My EF version is {6.1.3} My Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core version is {2.1.0}  and my                                                                              
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Entity... {2.1.0}

Comment: ok I also had this problem, please add your connection string in your question and run `Update-Database -Verbose` and show for me `Target database is:` in output.

Comment: are you trying to solve your problem?

Comment: yes I solve my problem

Comment: so what is your suggestion?

Comment: I say :  
ok I also had this problem, please add your connection string in your question and run Update-Database -Verbose and show for me Target database is: in output

Comment: I ran `update-database -verbose` and I got the script. Do I just execute this script on my prod?

Comment: no, I want: `Target database is`.